# Intellisense for Python APSW

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, apsw

System specs

Windows 10 Pro x64
Python 3.10.2 x64
APSW 3.37.0
Visual Studio Code 1.63.2

Intellisense works for Python and all imported modules except for APSW. APSW does work, and executing

```
dir(apsw)
```

Will yield all constants, functions, properties, etc contained in the apsw module, just no intellisense. My settings.json file in vscode has the following Python settings,

```
{
    /* Python ==== */
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python.exe",

    ...
}
```

I have removed apsw and reinstalled it nurmerous times using the *.msi installer, or *.whl with pip.

Anything I need to consider to get intellisense for apsw working?

Thanks and regards,
njc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APSW now ships with type stubs that also include the docstrings.  When using vscode you will get full intellisense.

(Disclosure: I am the APSW author)

Comment: That clears it up. APSW is the best SQLite3 wrapper I've used. Can't wait for the next release. Until then, I'll keep referencing your documentation wbsite.